# Why is my column null in C# when it has a given value in SQL Server output?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have two stored procedures which return data from an SQL Server database to C# code. They are almost identical but one deals with an extra parameter to select data from a Translation table for each of the respective reference tables.

Basic Procedure

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[BasicOutput]
@StartDate DATETIME2,
@EndDate DATETIME2,
@StartIndex INT,
@RowSize INT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @AreaCode NVARCHAR(20) = 'TEST' 

    SELECT * FROM
    (
        SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY d.[Date] ASC) AS RowNum, ISNULL(la.[Name], 'Not Specified') AS LA, ISNULL(ag.AgeGroup5yr, 'Not Specified') AS AgeGroupId, d.[Year], d.QuarterNameShort AS [Quarter], d.FinancialYearName + ' ' + d.FinancialQuarterNameShort AS FinancialYearAndQuarter, t.TimeBucket, d.DayOfWeekUK
        FROM dbo.TestData fa
        INNER JOIN dbo.DimDate d
        ON fa.AttendanceDateId = d.DateKey
        INNER JOIN dbo.DimTime t
        ON fa.AttendanceTimeId = t.TimeKey
        LEFT JOIN REF_LocalAuthority la
        ON fa.LA = la.LowerTierLAcode
        LEFT JOIN REF_AgeGroup ag
        ON fa.AgeGroupId = ag.ID
        WHERE d.[Date] >= @StartDate AND d.[Date] <= @EndDate
        AND (
            la.CtyCode = @AreaCode
            OR sc.CTYcode = @AreaCode
        )
    )a
    WHERE RowNum > @StartIndex AND RowNum <= (@StartIndex + @RowSize)
END
```

Translation Procedure

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[OutputWithTranslation]
@StartDate DATETIME2,
@EndDate DATETIME2,
@StartIndex INT,
@RowSize INT,
@TranslateLanguageCode NVARCHAR(10) = NULL
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @LanguageId INT = NULL
    DECLARE @NotSpecifiedText NVARCHAR(20) = 'Not Specified'
    IF(@TranslateLanguageCode IS NOT NULL)
    BEGIN
        SET @LanguageId = (SELECT Id FROM TranslationLanguage WHERE LanguageCode = @TranslateLanguageCode);
        SET @NotSpecifiedText = (SELECT TranslationText FROM REF_GenericResponse gr LEFT JOIN REF_GenericResponse_Translation grtran ON gr.Id = grtran.ResponseId WHERE gr.[Text] = @NotSpecifiedText AND grtran.LanguageId = @LanguageId)      
    END
    DECLARE @AreaCode NVARCHAR(20) = 'TEST' 

    SELECT * FROM
    (
        SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY d.[Date] ASC) AS RowNum, COALESCE(latran.TranslationText, la.[Name], @NotSpecifiedText) AS LA, ISNULL(ag.AgeGroup5yr, @NotSpecifiedText) AS AgeGroupId, d.[Year], d.QuarterNameShort AS [Quarter], d.FinancialYearName + ' ' + d.FinancialQuarterNameShort AS FinancialYearAndQuarter, t.TimeBucket, d.DayOfWeekUK
        FROM dbo.TestData fa
        INNER JOIN dbo.DimDate d
        ON fa.AttendanceDateId = d.DateKey
        INNER JOIN dbo.DimTime t
        ON fa.AttendanceTimeId = t.TimeKey
        LEFT JOIN REF_LocalAuthority la
        ON fa.LA = la.LowerTierLAcode

        LEFT JOIN REF_LocalAuthority_Translation latran
        ON la.ID = latran.LocalAuthorityId AND (@TranslateLanguageCode IS NOT NULL AND latran.LanguageId = @LanguageId)

        LEFT JOIN REF_AgeGroup ag
        ON fa.AgeGroupId = ag.ID

        WHERE d.[Date] >= @StartDate AND d.[Date] <= @EndDate
        AND (
        la.CtyCode = @AreaCode
        OR sc.CTYcode = @AreaCode
        )
    )a
    WHERE RowNum > @StartIndex AND RowNum <= (@StartIndex + @RowSize)
END
```

The output data in SQL Server is exactly the same (aside from the ordering because of joins/query optimiser), and the NULLs are correctly substituted for 'Not Specified' or its translation in both queries but when being returned to C# code, the result set from the translation stored procedure has NULL where the 'Not Specified' text should be. Is there something I'm missing with the code?

I have tried nested ISNULL statements in place of COALESCE to no avail. I have also tried adding the code to set @NotSpecifiedText in the first stored procedure and using a `COALESCE(NULL, la.[Name], @NotSpecifiedText)` and that seems to work fine...

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: Please show the c# code, where you are calling the translation procedure.  If TranslateLanguageCode is set incorrectly, then your languageId might remain NULL, in which case you would get the results you are experiencing.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please check this part of your stored procedure? Looks like it overwrites the `@NotSpecifiedText`:

```
SET @NotSpecifiedText = (SELECT TranslationText FROM REF_GenericResponse gr LEFT JOIN REF_GenericResponse_Translation grtran ON gr.Id = grtran.ResponseId WHERE gr.[Text] = @NotSpecifiedText AND grtran.LanguageId = @LanguageId)
```

Comment: That's intended. If the procedure is passed a `@TranslateLanguageCode` string from the C# code, it then gets 'Not Specified' text in the correct language. The issue is that the second procedure returns NULL in place of this text when the SQL Server output clearly shows the correct values.

Comment: And does your C# code have the `AgeGroupId` property to map the result?

Comment: Yep. Both stored procedures return the exact same dataset (columns/datatypes) but the second one doesn't seem to send through the columns where the null is replaced.

Comment: Could you please show your C# code, I would like to check how you are actually querying and mapping these stored procedures. Also, do you have any logs to see what is returning from the database? It seems to me there could be something wrong in the C# code.

Answer (score 0):

So, for some reason this seemed to fix the issue across all columns which checked for NULL.

I altered the stored procedure to update one section of the code to use an explicit NULL:

`COALESCE(NULL, la.[Name], @NotSpecifiedText) AS LA`

I ran the C# code with this and it worked. I then reverted the change to use the value from the LEFT JOIN table:

`COALESCE(latran.TranslationText, la.[Name], @NotSpecifiedText) AS LA`

...and it works as expected.

There was never any issue with the C# code (that only calls the stored procedure and returns the dataset to a web method). It has worked fine with the original "Basic" stored procedure and while also adding in the code to set the "Not Specified" text from the "Translation" procedure so there must have been some caching? not allowing the @NotSpecifiedText variable to be substituted when calling from external code.

I have a few more stored procedures to change over to work with translation tables so if I hit the same error then I'll re-open the question with any additional findings.